# htaccess in both root and subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a web root folder with a *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|images|js|sandbox)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Works a treat. Eg, browser requests to **www.site.com/images/image.png** will load the requested image, as expected.

I have a subfolder hanging off the root folder, called *sandbox*. It's pretty much an exact copy of the site. It has the same *htaccess* file as above.

Problem is, requests going to www.site.com/**sandbox**/images/image.png *do not work*.

I assume I need to make a change to the *htaccess* file in the *sandbox* subfolder, but I don't know what change is needed. Please help.. thanks.

Comment: `RewriteBase /sandbox/`?

Comment: Try to set RewriteBase to both files. If site.com is in the root of your server, it should be `RewriteBase /`, and sandbox' .htaccess should have `RewriteBase /sandbox/`. Edit: Mike Rocket faster.

Comment: What do the debug logs for the rewrite module say ([RewriteLog and
RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2, [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) ?

Comment: Thank you Mike Rockett and Tpojka, it's now working.